# Sending AT Commands to Remote XBee using python-serial

Tags: xbee, beaglebone-black, python

I have connected coordinator xbee to serial port of beaglebone i.e . tx and rx of beaglebone. My router's D0 pin is connected to relay. I want to remotely disable or enable the D0 pin. For that i am using python-xbee library. What I did is (my python code snippet)

```js
myRouter='\x00\x13\xA2\x00\x40\xE4\x29\xB3'
#For Off
xbee.remote_at(dest_addr_long=myRouter,command='D0',parameter='\x04')
#For switch ON
xbee.remote_at(dest_addr_long=myRouter,command='D0',parameter='\x05')
```

code is working fine without error but I am not getting the output.
I tried it using without beaglebone i.e. using usb explorer it works. Here is the [link of example @ digi](http://www.digi.com/blog/community/xbee-broadcast-tech-tip-using-remote-at-commands-to-toggle-an-io/).

I am using [python-xbee library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/XBee). What would be the error?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as you with my beaglebone. I got success only after I specify the frame_id.

```
xbee.remote_at(frame_id='\x01',dest_addr_long=myRouter,command='D0',parameter='\x04')
```

This is my whole code that works. Note that I broadcast (address FFFF) the command.

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import serial
from xbee import ZigBee
import time

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyO2', 9600)
xbee=ZigBee(ser)

myRouter = '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xFF\xFF'

xbee.remote_at(frame_id='\x01',dest_addr_long=myRouter,command='D0',parameter='\x04')
time.sleep(1)
response = xbee.wait_read_frame()
print response
```